# How to create adjacent plots on a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am newish to r/studio and am unsure how to tackle this problem.

Let's say I have a simple table like this:

| Year | Property 1 | Property 2 | Property 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 12 | 30 | 23 |
| 1995 | 20 | 39 | 28 |
| 1972 | 21 | 44 | 35 |

```
                                     ...
```

I am trying to create a boxplot using ggplot2 similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwb8J.png), creating a bar for each property beside each other for each decade.

My first simpler question regards grouping the rows by decade. I assume to do this I would add another property that contains a year's decade for each row, which I would pass to the x axis within the aesthetic of the function. Some clarity on the syntax of this ggplot() and geom_boxplot() functions would be much appreciated.

My second question is how this could be achieved to display adjacent plots for each decade. Do I create separate instances of geom_boxplot() for Property 1,2, and 3, or am I mistaken?

I have already experimented with the x and y aesthetics both of the ggplot() function and geom_boxplot()--as with separate instances of geom_boxplot()--and only overlapping boxplots have been produced. There are some gaps in my fundamental knowledge of r and using charts in particular, so any help with this could go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

First bring the data in long format, then use ggplot2's `geom_boxplot`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, group = Year, fill = factor(Year))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]